# Simple bash script doesn't cron properly

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line, cron

I'm attempting to cron a simple bash script on my macbook-pro laptop. Ultimately, I would like to first get this to work for bash script and then move on to my python scripts. I've created a simple bash file (named hello.sh) with the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World" >> /Users/myusername/Desktop/test.txt
```

And my `crontab -e` is designated as follows:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /Users/myusername/Desktop/bash-files/hello.sh
```

However, I get nothing after waiting a minute.

After googling around, I concluded that maybe I was running into the "gotcha" issue (cron reading different parameters than `env`). So I queued the following:

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

and it's output as follows

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
USER=myusername
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/Users/myusername
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/myusername
LOGNAME=myusername
_=/usr/bin/env
```

running `env` in my terminal produces the following relevant parameters:

```
SHELL=/bin/zsh
USER=myusername
PATH=/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
PWD=/tmp
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/myusername
LOGNAME=myusername
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I've added the above parameter settings to my hello.sh script but I still get nothing.

Can anyone point out to what my issue is here?

Comment: Try putting the script and text file directly in `/Users/myusername/`. macOS has an odd mechanism for blocking access to ~/Desktop and certain other dirs, so it would be good to rule that out.

Comment: oh wow it looks like executed my script and produced the text file! thanks!!

Comment: is it not possible to let the cron access ~/Desktop and below levels?

Comment: There probably is. Since it appears to be a macOS specific question unrelated to bash or cron syntax, you may find tips on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Related to MacOS sandboxing.

Comment: Walled gardens, sandboxes; what's next -- straight jackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[These are permission and path errors, easily resolved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8KsI.png)

[image: cron full disk access]

Look in system preferences to grant full disk access to your binaries and unset PATH in your scripts to catch any paths that are not complete.

I recommend `/usr/local/bin` for ease of maintaining any scripts you wish to have `launchd` or `cron` to schedule.

There’s no reason you can’t run from your user folder if that suits you, however.

Comment: thanks @bmike! It looks like this did the trick for me!